# How to proceed without timestamp at the time of saving the record in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to insert a record in table like following. but i got a error in sql query and the error is related to timestamp. the table which i am inserting in don't have 'updated_at' and 'created_at' column so can i proceed without that??

```
$member_bio = new barcodedb;
$member_bio->_code = $record['_code'];
$member_bio->_type = $record['_type'];
$member_bio->_name = $record['_name'];
$member_bio->_passwd = $record['_passwd'];
$member_bio->_privilege= $record['_privilege'];
$member_bio->_findex = $record['_findex'];
$member_bio->_fprint = $record['_fprint'];
$member_bio->_rfidcard = $record['_rfidcard'];
$member_bio->_bcode = $srno_record->bcode;
$member_bio->_bid = $srno_record->bid;
$member_bio->_change = 0;
$member_bio->_device = 1;
$member_bio->save();
```

**And the error is**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `member_bio` (`_code`, `_type`,
>   `_name`, `_passwd`, `_privilege`, `_findex`, `_fprint`, `_rfidcard`,
>   `_bcode`, `_bid`, `_change`, `_device`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (2345, M, 0, 1234, 0, 3, 6, 0, AS, 1, 0, 1, 2016-10-15
>   12:49:30, 2016-10-15 12:49:30))

Comment: In laravel, `created_at` and `updated_at` are key by default. And it is good practice to have those in your table as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `public $timestamps = false;` to your model.

If you wish not to have timestamps for **all** the models then add the property to `BaseModel` and extend all your models from the `BaseModel`.